# Multiple json respone get by Retrofit in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, retrofit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zpiV.png)

in the above json . i can get the link directly by this code ,
 private  String link;

```
public blog(String link) {
    this.link = link;


}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}
```

But how can i get the rendered string under content ,whereas is not direct like link .

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i'm usually using Kotlin. I tried to translate it to Java.

Class Response for Retrofit Call

```
public class Response {

    ...

    Content content;

}
```

Class Content

```
public class Content {

    String rendered;

}
```